# Android 10，huawei mate30 ,When I jump from the app to the APN settings page, there is no data！

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, apn

**When I use this way to jump to the APN settings page：**

```
intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS);
int subId = getDefaultDataSubId();
intent.putExtra("sub_id",subId );
startActivity(intent);
```

**it like this:**
[intent way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyY5o.jpg)

**But it's normal when I enter through the system settings：** 
[system settings way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8wFP.jpg)

Comment: try this in Intent constructor "android.settings.APN_SETTINGS" with flag 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: thanks,but It doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried this on two of our Dev-Phones here. On one it works, on the other I get the error "this setting is not available for the current user" - It worked on a Huawei P10 lite but it didn't work on a Nokia 6.1 --- So I guess, you are device-dependant here.

Comment: @Grisgram I guess so，thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Pixel, solved like this:

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS).apply {
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                putExtra(":settings:show_fragment_as_subsetting", true)
                putExtra("sub_id", SubscriptionManager.getDefaultDataSubscriptionId())
            })
```

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/network/telephony/ApnPreferenceController.java

---

But not working on Huawei.  T_T

Comment: Hi, it is recommended to not include links to external sources in the answers, it's better to add a code snippet in the answer instead.